# How to make a picture to cover the width of a div

Tags: css

On this [website](http://rainmakercorp.ch/) I would like to fit the picture for the entire div width.
(If you scroll down you'll see the blog section)

As you can see from the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYzaV.png) there are some white space on left and right.

How can I achieve this?

Note: I can't edit the HTML structure of the website. I can only work via CSS or JS.

Many many thanks

Comment: You mean stretching the image? `img {width:100%;height:auto;}`

Comment: `img {width : 100%;margin 0 auto;}`

Comment: if all your images are going to be the same size (originally) then I would use width 100% with height auto, if not but you have a fixed ratio container, then I would use object fit with the ie polyfill

Comment: Also, please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE].  And finally, please take time to read this  [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: I don't know why this is being flagged as off-topic. Admittedly there is no code, but the question is directly code related?!

Comment: @LokiSinclair https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - number one on the list read it carefully to see why this is off topic

Comment: @Pete Respectfully, I'm quite aware of the guidelines and rules. Yet, I've seen far worse questions be left alone/open.

Comment: @LokiSinclair You asked, I was just showing you "Admittedly there is no code" is in direct contravention of the rule (at the top of the page it says that although a question may be directly about programming, it can still be off topic) - this question is also still open, btw.  I have also seen worse questions than this upvoted, it's just about people's opinions in the end and whether they think it breaks the rules

Answer (score 1):

You only have a `max-width: 100%`- So if you set `width: 100%` it'll work, like so:

```
img.scale-with-grid, #Content img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

As can be seen here (updated css in chrome devtools.) [image]

Answer (score 0):

Just give `img.scale-with-grid, #Content img` : `width:100%`